# Eclipse JEE Mars.2 Inspect not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I was previously using Jboss Dev Studio (based on an older version of Eclipse) in Windows and was able to execute selected code using the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+I (when I hit a breakpoint in debug mode). A popup would appear with the result of the execution, which was extremely helpful.

I just setup Mars.2 JavaEE (4.5.2) to start a different project and am finding that this command no longer works. Under preferences->general->keys I definitely have the same shortcut (Inspect = Ctrl+Shift+i) but when I use that command, it simply obliterates the selected code and replaces it with a space! Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different keybindings are active depending on where you are, so in which perspective and editor is this overwriting the selection?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see this response sooner! I shutdown and restarted eclipse and it seems to be working now. I have seen it do this at least twice more recently - the key combo which has always worked in previous versions, somehow fails to execute correctly here. It's a minor annoyance but at least there's an easy workaround. Thanks for your response!